# How to echo full list of rows in php mysql using while loops but outside the loop

Tags: php, mysql, do-loops

Hello please help me is this code this code only show me last row of loop not full.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT hash FROM users");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $url = $row["hash"]."<br />";

}
```

> 5b50373f0dbd8ab7fe888060257967f2e0adcbdb

but full list is:

> a065e7094234b1c836f9829ca9185a36132ff76f
>   5b50373f0dbd8ab7fe888060257967f2e0adcbdb

pleas help me

Comment: Make `$url` an array, or concatenate it with a new line...

Comment: Or `$url .= $row["hash"]."<br />";`

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) [statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: Any issues or questions with either of the provided answers? http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: You need to explain the problem a bit more, maybe show the table structure.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this one of three ways. Currently you are resetting `$url` on every iteration.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT hash FROM users");
$url = '';
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $url .= $row["hash"] . "<br />";

}
```

or

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT hash FROM users");
$url = '';
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    echo $row["hash"] . "<br />";

}
```

or

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT hash FROM users");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $url[] = $row["hash"] . "<br />";
}
```

With this approach you need to iterate through the array later, `foreach`..

Comment: I have been racking my brain (for about an hour now) on something I'm working on in order to be able to echo out more than one row "outside" a loop where I couldn't "echo" inside a loop, since I have about a dozen different sections in a bootstrapped site that requires echoing just a variable and not a whole bunch of "in and out" PHP loops. Your first suggestion was the one that worked for me Chris; the others did not. I'll be keeping this one "on file". *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Glad someone was able to use it.

Comment: It has Chris; for me anyway and "thanks" for having submitted the answer that may very well help others also. I'm sure the OP got their solution but just ran off. It's not like they haven't been told what to do with the answers given neither. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for `foreach`:

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT hash FROM users");
$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $url = $row["hash"]."<br />";
}
?>
```

Plus, you're overwriting the `$url` variable each iteration. Either push each value onto an array, or concatenate a string:

```
<?php
// ...
$urls = '';
$url_list = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $urls .= $row['hash'].'<br>'; // concatenation
    $url_list[] = $row['hash']; // add each URL to an array
}
?>
```

Then you can either output the final string, or iterate over the array when you want to recall the values.

Comment: Why? Doesn't `while` work just as well in this case? You're still overwriting `$url` each time.

Comment: Oh. Oops. Your problem is that you're overwriting the `$url` variable each time. You should either use concatenation (`$url .= $row["hash"];`) or add them to an array (`$url_list[] = $row["hash"];`).

Comment: You still haven't said why `foreach` is a good use case here.

Comment: I prefer it for style reasons since I find the `while` syntax a bit weird.

Comment: That's cool, but if you're going to say something to the effect of *"This is a good use case for..."* you need to explain why.